# How to use azure key vault android application

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, azure-keyvault

Am new to Azure. I want to know know to access key vault access android application.

If you have any reference or sample. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is for Notification hub. I want for Key vault.

Comment: If I am not wrong you may try using REST interface for Key Vault 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/

Comment: I already run through that doc, But I need a sample with more detail. How to implement.

Comment: @user1182201 there isn't any android sample I am able to find right now but you can check these samples based on JAVA and might help you out.

https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=azure+key+vault&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @user1182201 What do you want to do for using Azure Key Vault on Android?

Answer (score 0):

There are two samples using KeyVault in Java on Azure offical GitHub sample repository.

1. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-java-manage-key-vaults
2. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-keyvault-java-management

Hope it helps.